# How to use an aggregate in an order by in DataMapper?

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I've got a simple class like:

```
class Foo
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :bar, Text, lazy: false
    property :created_on, DateTime, default: lambda { |r,p| DateTime.now }
end
```

I want to select them, grouped by bar and ordered by max(created_on). The SQL I need is:

```
SELECT "bar" FROM "foo" GROUP BY "bar" ORDER BY MAX("created_on") DESC
```

but I don't know how to get this with DataMapper.

I've tried something like:

```
Foo.all(fields: [:bar], unique: true, order: [:created_on.desc.max])
```

but you can't use max like that. I can't find out how to do it.

Can you help?

Comment: I had this same problem and couldn't figure out a "good" solution. The things I did were call to either SQL directly or add a field that's an aggregate (which I don't think would work in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if using the max aggregate is not necessary. By ordering in descending order of the created_on column its going to find the MAX and go from there.

You could probably get away with:

```
Foo.all(fields: [:bar], unique: true, order: [created_on.desc])
```

without using .max in the order.

This would be same as:

```
SELECT "bar" FROM "foo" GROUP BY "bar" ORDER BY "created_on" DESC
```

Hope this works.

Also take a look at
http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html